# Send email with $this->email->from from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

please help me how to use $this->email->from with database. I only can use 'admin@yahoo.com' but can't send email with $cf['dm']. $cf get info from database and use type varchar

```
$this->email->from('admin@yahoo.com', "Ticket ID");
$this->email->from($cf['dm'], "Ticket ID");
```

Comment: can you send mail by using $this->email->from('admin@yahoo.com', "Ticket ID"); but can't send by using $this->email->from($cf['dm'], "Ticket ID");  ?????

Comment: Have u `vardump` or `print_r` $cf['dm'] ??

Comment: can you add model code as well??

Comment: Please edit your question with rest of your controller and model would be use full.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try by saving `$from=$cf['dm'];` And then `$this->email->from($from, "Ticket ID");`
Also provide more details of your controller and model,only then we will be able to help you out with more suggestions.